# How do i get JavaFX 8 Date Picker CSS Properties

Tags: css, user-interface, javafx-8, datapicker

I want to style default javaFX date picker to our custom theme, but i cant see any Documentation/Guide to change CSS proprties.

any help would be appricated

Default javaFX  Calender style

[image]

I want to customize its color to match below guideline

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the [source code for the default stylesheet](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css). The code relevant to date picker is at lines 1719-1753 and from 2932 onwards. Experiment with an external stylesheet that overrides these and update your question with specific details if you can't make it work.

Comment: @James_D hmm ... shouldn't available styles be documented somewhere (outside the sources)?

Comment: @kleopatra Yes, absolutely. The [CSS Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) is useful, but it is pretty incomplete, and doesn't include what I find to be the most useful: what looked-up colors are defined and which controls use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best documentation, in this case, can be default CSS file called **modena.css**. This style sheet is applied for every JavaFX components.

You can find this file in the JavaFX jar file **jfxrt.jar** (should be located */jdk1.8.x/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar*). After unzipping that jar file you should find the **modena.css** under *com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/*

Find in the file a commented section **DatePicker** (in my file it's line# 2999) and you get all style properties that you are looking for.

Hope it helps.